# What makes someone eligible in clash of clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

So I tried to start a war with my clan, Fallout. We had ten people at the time but when I had attempted to start a war it said I did not have enough eligible players. What makes someone eligible in clash of clans and exact

Comment: This question has been answered [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163710/requirements-for-a-clan-war).

Answer (score 1):

> "Members who are new to your clan will be ineligible for war if they left their previous clan while a war was in progress. They will become eligible for war again when the previous war is completed. You can check your clan member list to see if any members are ineligible for war, and see when they will be eligible again. If you start the clan war while members are still ineligible, those members will not be able to participate."

[Supercell FAQ](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/232849-Clan-Wars-FAQ)

Comment: It should also be noted that clan members are ineligible if they left their previous clan while it was at war. Source: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/163710/requirements-for-a-clan-war

Comment: @crgsqdmn??  That's exactly what my post says